# Silicone or plumbers putty?

Tags: plumbing

Replacing my tub.

Below the tub is the PVC drain and it comes with a rubber gasket.

Then the tub-drain unit screws into the drain from inside the tub to make the connection.

I watched a video that said silicone was better than plumbers putty.

I've always used plumbers putty...Is silicone really better than plumbers putty?

I assume the silicone would never go on the PVC drain rubber gasket.

Do I still use Teflon tape on threads if using silicone?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The rubber gasket replaces both. Plumber's putty is mostly obsolete these days (almost everything comes with rubber or neoprene washers) and can stain fixtures, and silicone is never a good material for joining water-bearing plumbing components.

You could use PTFE tape as a secondary measure and a thread lubricant. Be sure to wrap it the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the rubber seal that comes in the box, because it is usually thick and causes standing water.

They sell 2 types of plumber's putty: regular and a non-staining one.
Old-school putty has been around for long time for a reason. It will dry out at some point; but rubber swells over time, so pick your poison.

Comment: You're using the gasket incorrectly. It belongs _under_ the sink. Sometimes there's a second very thin one which would go on top, but that's going to compress to almost nothing.